# Accout page links are not showing in mobile

Tags: magento2.3, account-dashboard

Once I have logged in our website, I can see the account page with the links. Please see the below screenshot:

[image]

But the links are not displaying in mobile view. Please see the below screenshot:

[image]

How can i show the links in mobile view?

Comment: Check by inspect element, If you are using custom theme, then the links can be hidden somewhere in theme.

Comment: @siva are you using the luma theme or any other theme?

Comment: We have extended the Luma theme. I have checked and see that the links are set to display none. How can I show those links as a menu in mobile view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account page links should show at the mobile view. If you check at top of `Account Information`  section a text is "My Account".If you will click on it then you see links of account left.

[image]

**When you will click on it open  like:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out me about this.